# Is there any way to customize a TDBadgedCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I tried to changed the background of the TDBadgedCell to get more customized feeling.
By default the TDBadgedCell background is transparent. So you can see through the cell and see the (by default) white background color of the tableview.

I already tried to do this:

```
cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
```

But it seems not to be working. Instead of changing the background view color I also tried on the contentView and the cell view itself. None of them working properly (the background color of the UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator stays still transparent).

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: because cell.backgroundView is nil. You should try to init it first. cell.backgroundView = [UIView alloc] init]. Then you can set the color.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I did not think about that the background view was nil. This solved the problem

Comment: Ok. I reposted comment to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because cell.backgroundView is nil. You should try to init it first. cell.backgroundView = [UIView alloc] init]. Then you can set the color.